# Meaning of casting the address of a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

Lately, while working in C, I was developing a generic function.
Here is the layout of structure:

```
typedef struct student_{
    char name[32];
    int roll_no;
    unsigned int height;
} student_t;
```

and below is my function. What all the function does is, it compares the given instance of a structure with one of the keys ( and hence generic). Here the key being **roll_no**

```
static int
check_student_by_roll_number(void *data,void *key){
    student_t * student = (student_t*) data;
    unsigned int roll_no = *(unsigned int*)(key); // Getting segmentation fault here
    if(student->roll_no == roll_no)return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

But the same fault code, when I write as

```
unsigned int roll_no = *(unsigned int*)(&key);
```

I am calling the function as

```
check_student_by_roll_number(john,(void*)40); // john is a pointer to valid structure
```

The segmentation fault is gone and code works fine.So what is difference between
`*(unsigned int*)(key)` and  `*(unsigned int*)(&key)`

Comment: You're passing an `int` (`40`) hard-cast to `void*`. That doesn't mean the function gets the address of some memory location where a `40` resides. It means you literally manufacturing a pointer with the scalar value `40` .  That pointer clearly doesn't point to anything valid, so the dereference invokes undefined behavior. Regarding the non-"crash" code, all `*(unsigned int*)(&key)` is doing is casting a `void**` to an `unsigned int*`, then dereferencing it, which isn't really what you want either.

Comment: @WhozCraig can you please tell me, what is the behaviour of that manufactured pointer ?

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, `key` is treated as some kind of integer type. `key` doesn't contain a pointer, so dereferencing it is clearly wrong.

To get back `40` from `(void*)40`, you need `(int)(void*)40`.

You could also cast straight to `unsigned int` which is what you want here.

```c
unsigned int roll_no = (unsigned int)key;
```

---

Generally speaking, storing an integer value in a variable expected to hold a pointer isn't safe. At least not on machines with trap representations. But there's no issue on a x86 or x86-64 (as long as the pointer is large enough to store the integer).

`*(unsigned int*)&key` is worse. It assumes the memory layout of a `void*` is identical to that of an `unsigned int`. This won't be the case on the big-endian machine if the types have different sizes. It will effectively work on a little-endian machine (as long as the integer type is no larger than the pointer type). Might as well use the inverse of what you used outside the function (`(unsigned int)key`) and avoid using a second hack in addition to your first.

Comment: In general, can you explain me the difference between int* p = (int*) x and int* p = (int*) &x ?? What does that additional & sign does ? Here, you can consider x as a void pointer which points to a valid integer data.

Comment: `x` gets the value of `x`. `&x` creates a pointer to `x`.

Comment: But to get x value of x, there must be a de referencing first right? as x is itself a pointer ?

Comment: There's no dereferencing (`*E`, `E->`, `E[]`, `E()`) here. Yes, the value of `x` is a pointer.

Comment: Is there any thumb rule for typecasting of void pointers ?

Comment: Only do so to recuperate a pointer that was previously casted to a `void*`. Or for the result of an `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254685/discussion-between-stardep-and-ikegami).